# Django Model Сортировка Записей

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет. В проекте django в вью `views.load(request)` приходит json массив с id публикаций. Нужно выбрать из модели Publication все записи с pk которые равны id из массива. Первая мысль это сделать в цикле но может есть какой то другой метод?

Comment: `Publication.objects.filter(pk=ID)`

Comment: @floydya Вы меня не поняли у меня есть список ID c нужными id. Нужно из Publication выбрать только те которые равны id из списка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
filtered_publications = Publication.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)
```

[Соответствующий раздел документации.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in)